# Print multidimensional array in rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, view

In my controller I do:

```
@categories = Category.all
for i in @categories.min.id..@categories.max.id
   @allposts.push(Post.where(:Category => i))
end
```

In views(haml) i do

```
<% @allposts.each do |posts, slots| %>
  <% @slots.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.Title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And i see this error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass on @slots.each do |post|.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you keep trying to use `@slots` ? As inside the block you created as `|posts, slots|`...

Comment: @Saska  If `Category` is associated with model `Post` with `1-M relationship` then you can simply loop over `@categories` like `@categories.each do |category|` `category.posts` to get all the posts associated with a given category. Why to make multidimensional arrays and complicate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is :

```
<% @allposts.each do |posts, slots| %>
  <% slots.each do |post| %>  # <--- see I removed @ symbol
    <%= post.Title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Your block variable is `slots`, and you attempted as `@slots`. Which I think is a typo. As there is no such `@slots` variable defined, you got `nil`, when you wanted to use it. There is a sweet difference between local variable and instance variable. If you don't defined anywhere a local variable say `foo`, you will be ended up with **undefined local variable or method** if you want to use `foo` anywhere else.But for *instance variable*, no error, you will silently get `nil`.

Comment: Just 41 sec behind from your answer :)

Comment: @Pavan Yes.. may be 10 more seconds less.. My mouse's right click was not working.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined `@slots` in the method.Perhaps you mean `slots`.

```
<% @allposts.each do |posts, slots| %>
  <% slots.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.Title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```